# How can I put an image after/before options?

Tags: html, css

I made select box.

```
<select>
  <option>AAAA</option>
  <option>BBBB</option>
  <option>CCCC</option>
  <option>DDDD</option>
</select>
```

And I want to put an image after 
So I tried using before and after.
But it's not work.
How can solve this problem???

Comment: give some example of result and your css code

Comment: Even if it's theoretically possible using some trick, I would rather use Bootstrap dropdowns: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/. The advantages are that you will have the same look and feel across the browsers, adding images or other stuff will be straightforward and it's totally supported by major browsers